# Multiple node applications nginx configurations

Tags: nginx, nodejs

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain1.com www.domain1.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain2.com www.domain2.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    }
}
```

I have two simple server blocks, domain1.com works, domain2.com however does not have a successful proxy, and hits the node app running @ localhost:3000.  However, domain2.com:3001 does correctly go to 3001.

Any advice, I'm sure it's something simple.